# What is the verb for “arranged marriage”?

Tags: verbs

Can you say:

His father married him off to an arranged marriage.

She was arranged to be married.

What verbs do the people arranging the marriage take? What about the people arranged to be married?

Comment: His father arranged his marriage. Her marriage was arranged.

Comment: @JEL If you are going to use *arranged* in that way, you really need to put the word in quotation marks, to avoid the everyday sense, suggesting that the father just made the arrangements for the marriage ceremony and reception. Personally I would not say it in that way for that reason. I would always state that it had been *an arranged marriage*. *Hers was an arranged marriage* avoids any confusion.

Comment: @WS2, sans context, I guess there might be a possibility of confusion. In context, I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

Betrothed is probably the only single-word verb you'll find--while its usage has changed over the centuries, it was invented at a time (13th century) when most marriages were arranged, so its earliest meaning corresponds to what you're after. It wasn't until the 18th century that marriage for love entered the picture, so any usage earlier than the 18th century likely implies an arranged marriage.

Quick article on history of marriage: http://theweek.com/articles/475141/how-marriage-changed-over-centuries

Etymology of verb betroth:  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=betroth&allowed_in_frame=0